# InfoPath encounters SSL error with RESTful service on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, rest, ssl

My settings are:

- Excel file on SharePoint documents library.
- InfoPath form on SharePoint as a content type that makes RESTful call to Excel file and get data from its ranges. I don't use the data connection file for InfoPath but I manually set it in a rule.

It works fine with HTTP, but when comes into HTTPS, there's a error message:

http://flic.kr/p/edeYMC

How to get rid of this? Is there a way to fix at InfoPath side? Or a settings on SharePoint side?

Comment: Why do you store the info in an excel file instead of as its own list?

Comment: I followed an article. The InfoPath will make a REST service call to Excel file with the values for certain ranges (inputted into InfoPath form). The Excel will do the calculation and put the result into its appropriate range. My InfoPath will look into that range for result. Purpose is exposing the form for user to input but hiding the calculation.